# How should I fix this python TabError?

Tags: python

This is a part of an "Oregon Trail" remake that I am making. Here is the bit of code with the problem:

```
if option == '3':
    print('Clothes cost: 2 per set')
    print('Recomended: 12 sets')
    try:
        clothnum = int(input('How many sets of clothes: '))
        clothmon = clothnum * 2
    except:
        print('')
```

And on the `try:` statement (on the colon to be exact) it raises this error:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I checked the whole code, and I can't see anything wrong with the indentation.

Comment: Use a text editor such as notepad++ that will show whitespace characters. The message is clear. You're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Use a text editor which can display tabs and white spaces. Or find a setting which converts tabs to white spaces.

Comment: Ok I used the "find keyword" function in my compiler an found out that some of my indents were just 4 spaces.

Comment: Worth noting that the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) style standard prescribes 4 spaces per indentation level, no tabs.

Comment: Note that SO's formatter converts tabs to 4 spaces, but you can see the tabs if you [view the source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bd3715c8-572c-4931-8851-c202e1202d17/view-source).

Comment: "I checked the whole code, and I can't see anything wrong with the indentation." - do you understand what a tab is, and what a space is? Is there a difference between a tab and a bunch of spaces? Can you **see** that difference? Do you understand the problem with that reasoning?